# IIS website showing login panel

Tags: iis, authorization

The default website for my IIS (windows 7) shows a login box everytime you try to browse it. When I press cancel, I get a 401 error.

How do I remove this and allow anyone to access anything on my IIS? Default website, virtual applications, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS click the default website, then in the right panel double click authentication.  Anonymous Access should be set to enabled.

*please note these directions are specific to Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to go the the folder of the default website and give the IIS User and IIS Application user privileges to the folder.

I am not sure what Windows 7 calls these users, but they should start with an I.

Comment: It's possible - however by default this should be set.  That being said the Anonymous Access should have been enabled by default as well, so it's hard to say.